# HTML/CSS display Elements in nice manner

Tags: html, css, asp.net, stylesheet

So, the reason for my disturbance, I need to put these TextBoxes, Labels, Buttons in a pretty line among themselves.
For some of you this might be easy doing in CSS, so please help me :D

Any reference where I can read about it would be nice too.

Extra Info:
Website is based on ASP.NET

**EDIT1:**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioListRight" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
        <asp:ListItem>Recht hinzufuegen</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Recht entfernen</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:Label ID="LabelError" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>

    <br />
    Projekt:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="comboProj" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="140px" Visible="False">
    </asp:DropDownList><br />
    &nbsp;Teilprojekt:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:DropDownList ID="ComboTP" runat="server" Width="136px" Visible="False">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddTP" runat="server" Text="Hinzufügen" Visible="False" />
    <br />
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxTP" runat="server" Height="164px" Width="422px" Visible="False"></asp:ListBox><br />
    Art der Berechtigungen:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="comboBerechtigungsArt" runat="server" Visible="False" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Auswählen...</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="CHECK-IN / CHECK-OUT"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>CHECK-OUT</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>CHECK-IN</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList><br />
    Berechtigungen eintragen für&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUser" runat="server" Width="151px" placeholder="HendrikHeim" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" runat="server" Text="Hinzufügen" Visible="False" />
    <br />
    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="labelEmail" runat="server" Text="EMail"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Show us the code! Check this link - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp

Comment: Done that, does it help?

Comment: Try it first before asking for help. Flexbox in css is super easy to use and understand. <a href="https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/">Flexbox Guide</a> This guide is well documented. So, you will easily understand it. Try to read it for 30mins. Then it will be easy for you in layouting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use tables, use CSS and 'div' nodes to wrap the content and the display style to  put the data inline.

Use http://www.w3schools.com/

As a source for CSS

Tables will not flow correctly if the browser width is to narrow, putting into individual tags will allow the browser to style the layout correctly.

To put elements on the same row:

```
    <div style="display:inline;width:80px;">content here</div>
    <div style="display:inline;width:100px;">content here</div><br />
```

You can then fix the width of the columns by adding more styles, width etc.

If you are unfamiliar with CSS, then spend some time learning it.

Comment: So whats the command to have them all among themselves? For example input Textboxes?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking/

Comment: As in every Button is exactly among.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfm1j.png like here

"Hinzufügen" and "Bearbeitung abschließen" exactly underneath "Hinzufügen" without whitespaces in front so that its not exactly underneath

Comment: I will modify my answer to include more detail.